# Average Scrabble graph structure: diameter?

Tags: graph-theory, recreational-mathematics, combinatorial-game-theory

Tonight a game of Scrabble ended in what I consider a very unusual graph structure,
unlike this generic web image, which seems more typical:

            [image]
Let us call the *Scrabble graph* the one whose nodes are tiles, with two tiles connected
by an arc in the graph if they share a side.
The unusual graph that occurred contained a long snaking chain that consumed most of the board.
This made me wonder if anyone has performed a statistical analysis of "average" Scrabble
graphs; for example, their diameter, or their cycle structure? 
No doubt these properties depend on the skill of the players, but
it seems within some reasonable parameters, there are perhaps answers of sorts.  I would be curious to
hear of any data in this direction.  Thanks!

**Afterthought**. Maybe equally interesting: What is the largest diameter legal, achievable Scrabble graph?

Comment: It turns out testae does not mean what I would have expected.

Comment: There is a database of scrabble games available at http://www.cross-tables.com/annolistself.php

Comment: It would also be interesting to consider the following graph: The vertices are the words on the final board, and two vertices are joined by an edge, iff they share a "letter piece". Of course, both graphs are somehow related.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## Methods

Starting from the base url http://www.cross-tables.com/annotated.php?a=1 I used a combination of Python's `urllib`, `multiprocessing` and `BeautifulSoup` to extract the first 10000 games. The games were parsed and turned into `numpy` 15x15 Boolean matrices. The matrices were then turned into graphs making an edge if two adjacent cells in the matrix were both active. Graph properties were then analysed with `networkx`

Of the 10000 games, only 9966 were usable. Some games [did not start on the center title](http://www.cross-tables.com/annotated.php?u=2195), while others [ended so quickly and strangely](http://www.cross-tables.com/annotated.php?u=3671#4#) they did not behave properly. Fortunately these games were rare enough that the sample should give a robust estimation of the true distributions.

## Methods (Update)

There was a bit more data cleanup needed. I had not taken into consideration challenged moves, leading to games that had >100 tiles used. In the process, I noted [false moves](http://www.cross-tables.com/annotated.php?u=5341#27#) and [fake games](http://www.cross-tables.com/annotated.php?u=1952#0#). We may have to live with a bit of uncertainty in the data, such is the cost of true empirical data.

## Results

The first interesting piece of information is the board frequency - this gives a nice spatial connection to the graphs we are about to study. Notice that, due to how the game is played (and how we read left to right and top to bottom) the board is asymmetric.

[image: Board frequency]

From here we can answer the question,

> "What is the distribution of graph diameters and radii for an average
> Scrabble game?"

[image]

A scatter plot versus the graph size reveals a bit more information for the smaller $N$ values:

[image]

## Results (Update)

Based of a comment, I plotted the radius vs the diameter, giving a mostly linear relationship of 1 to 2 except for a range of games with some variance. Feel free to make some observations on the significance of this in the comments.

[image]

## Quick Conclusion (TLDR)

From the data studied, there were mostly full games played ~100 tiles with an average graph radius 18 and a diameter of 36. Further work is needed to compare these results to random graphs with the same size and edge counts but different edge distribution.

Comment: Please leave a comment if you would like any more statistics to be run against the data and I'll add it in.

Comment: This is cool. Could you also generate statistics, considering the graph of words, instead the graph of tiles (see my second comment of the question).

Comment: Aside from your interesting results, your analysis is based on an impressive piece of programming, using many tools masterfully---Kudos!  It is at least pleasing that the radius is half the diameter. :-)  One question: How can $N$ exceed 100, as there are exactly 100 tiles?

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke This reflects my unfamiliarity with Scrabble (though I should have checked). You are right that a game only has 100 tiles - the extra tiles come from a game like http://www.cross-tables.com/annotated.php?u=9890, where a word was successfully challenged, thus removing it from the board. I didn't know that was possible, nor did I expect it would be recorded as a move. The upside is, while currently incorrect, they make up a small portion of the graph < 10% and do not affect all games. When I get some time, I'll try and fix this - thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke and in looking at those extra challenge words I come across games like http://www.cross-tables.com/annotated.php?u=1952#22#. I'm not a linguist, but I think that the English Stack Exchange folks will tell me that "joohampers" and "reactivevolosts" are not in the Scrabble dictionary, never mind the fact that the record points to an excess number of tiles being used. Point being, some games must not be valid. I only counted 4 of these in the dataset.

Comment: Impressive work! But there's a lot of [overplotting](http://gettinggeneticsdone.blogspot.com/2012/07/fix-overplotting-with-colored-contour.html) going on in those scatterplots. Perhaps [a density plot](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hexbin) would be better.

Comment: Which tool did you use to make the figures?

Comment: @aromero All plots were made with `matplotlib` (`pylab`) on Python. As suggested by Rahul, a hexplot in the pylab library might be better for the scatter plots.

Comment: [This game](https://www.cross-tables.com/annotated.php?u=2195) must've been played on a 19x19 board, with 9-letter racks and 13 blanks (if I counted right). Click on the "25" to see all the plays.

Comment: "due to how the game is played (and how we read left to right...) the board is asymmetric." That's not why. One factor is that some games get confined to a lower-right triangle because the SW-NE diagonal fills with letters that are rare enders (J, V, Q are particularly rare but even A, I, O, U are fairly rare). It is not so often a problem that play from a tile cannot go down/rightwards because it is a rare starter. The reason why the middle row's left half & middle column's top half are unlike might be the custom to play the 1st word horizontally.

Answer (score 10):

It turns out that the maximum possible diameter uses the full hundred tiles! My friend Carl illustrated this in 2008 in a game he made up, here: http://www.cross-tables.com/annotated.php?u=2493#0# .

Thanks for the question!

Comment: Very clever!!! $\;$

Answer (score 2):

If you require the viable dictionaries that are allowable for scrabble, they are available on the http://www.lexicalwordfinder.com/about/ site (Lexical Word Finder website).

An interesting experiment:  Assuming most people do not play expertly, you can use the generated list from Lexical Word finder to play *medium* words to see what the average graphs look like.  It would be nice to also see what the "best" moves at each turn produce as well.

Interesting use of networkx.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a 100-tile diameter-99 game. (If you insist that only 99 tiles can be played as the player who didn't go out must have one tile, just leave out that last p.)

```
   A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O
 1 B E E R I E S T . . . + . . # 1
 2 O = . . . * . E R U P T I N G 2
 3 T . = . . . + . + . . . = . R 3
 4 A . . = . . . p h O N E S . A 4
 5 N . . . = . . . . . = . E . V 5
 6 I * . . . * A I R L I F T * I 6
 7 C O U G H E D . + . . . + . E 7
 8 # . . + . . . M E Z Q U I T S 8
 9 K A L E W I F E + . . . + . . 9
10 V * . . . * . . . * . . . * . 10
11 E . . . = . . . P O L Y O M A 11
12 T . B O L O G N A . . = . . X 12
13 C . = . . . + . + . . . = . I 13
14 H = . . . * . A D J O U R N S 14
15 Y A R D W A N D . . . + . . # 15
   A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O
```

8H MEZQUIT

9B ALEWIFE

A9 KVETCHY

15A (Y)ARDWAND

14H ADJOURN

O12 XIS

11I POLYOMA

12C BOLOGNA

O2 GRAVIES

2H ERUPTIN(G)

1B EERIEST

A1 BOTANIC

7A (C)OUGHED

6G AIRLIFT

M4 SE(T)

4H phONE(S)